# Unable to create format checking for text file using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I have a .material file in my engine that currently looks like this:

```
diffuse:res/textures/container.png
specular:res/textures/containerspecular.png
displacement:res/textures/containerdisplacement.png
d_slot:0
s_slot:1
ds_slot:2
shineness:12.0
displacement_factor:0.2
```

I'm currently using a naive aproach to extract the attributes:

```
/* --------------Diffuse ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            diffuseTexture = line;
            diffuseTexture = diffuseTexture.substr(line.find("diffuse:") + 8, line.length() - 8);


            /* --------------Specular ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            specularTexture = line.substr(line.find("specular:") + 9, line.length() - 9);

            /* --------------Displacement-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            displacementTexture = line.substr(line.find("displacement:") + 13, line.length() - 13);

            /* --------------Diffuse Slot -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            diffSlot = std::stoi(line.substr(line.find("d_slot:") + 7, line.length() - 7));

            /* --------------Specular Slot -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            specSlot = std::stoi(line.substr(line.find("s_slot:") + 7, line.length() - 7));

            /* --------------Displacement Slot ---------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            dispSlot = std::stoi(line.substr(line.find("ds_slot:") + 8, line.length() - 8));

            /* --------------Shineness------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            shineness = std::stof(line.substr(line.find("shineness:") + 10, line.length() - 10));

            /* --------------Displacement Factor--------------------------------------------------------------*/
            getline(myfile, line);
            displacementFactor = std::stof(line.substr(line.find("displacement_factor:") + 20, line.length() - 20));

            myfile.close();
```

so i was looking up Regex, but just couldt'n make the regex to check the format.
If somoene could please help me ou it would be much aprecciated.
Also should i extract the data using the matches from regex or just check if the file is in proper format and then apply my aproach? Thanks.

```
bool Material::_checkFileFormat(const String& filepath)
    {
        std::ifstream t(filepath);
        std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

        std::smatch matches;
        std::regex reg("(diffuse:)");

        std::sregex_iterator currentMatch(str.begin(), str.end(), reg);
        std::sregex_iterator lastMatch;

        while (currentMatch != lastMatch) 
        {
            std::smatch match = *currentMatch;
            std::cout << match.str() << "/n";
            currentMatch++;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: In your original code you don't seem to check if the data you are reading conforms to the format. Although I would use that general approach rather than regex for this.

Comment: Does the data in the file always appear in the same order? Is each item mandatory or are some optional?

Comment: The data aleays apears the same way for now all maps are mandatory, my fear of regex is efficiency. But it looks like the most elegant solution.

Comment: The thing is using regex to identify if the text file matches the correct material format wich is (diffuse:%s \n %s displacement:%s\n d_slot:%d \n s_slot:%d \n ds_slot:%d\n shineness:%f\n
displacement_factor:%f \n) with the proper code I will be able to change it to fit my needs as the engine grows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As galik said, the general aproach was the best solution.

```
void Material::_checkFileFormat(const String& filepath)
{


    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::ifstream myMaterialFile(filepath);

    while (!myMaterialFile.eof() && myMaterialFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string temp;
        getline(myMaterialFile, temp);
        lines.push_back(temp);
    }

    myMaterialFile.close();

    int line_number = 0;
    for(std::string line : lines)
    {
        line_number++;

        switch (line_number) 
        {
            case 1:
                if (line.find("diffuse:") == std::string::npos)
                {
                    MAGMA_FATAL("Error in reading diffuse texture");
                }
                    break;
            case 2:
                if (line.find("specular:") == std::string::npos)
                {
                    MAGMA_FATAL("Error in reading specular map");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (line.find("displacement:") == std::string::npos)
                {
                    MAGMA_FATAL("Error in reading displacement map");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (line.find("d_slot:") == std::string::npos)
                {
                    MAGMA_FATAL("Error in reading diffuse slot");
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (line.find("s_slot:") == std::string::npos)
                {
                    MAGMA_FATAL("Error in reading specular slot");
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if (line.find("ds_slot:") == std::string::npos)
                {
                    MAGMA_FATAL("Error in reading displacement slot");
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (line.find("shineness:") == std::string::npos)
                {
                    MAGMA_FATAL("Error in reading shineness");
                }
                break;                  
        }

    }   

}
```

in the code i check for existence of textures in disk:

```
if (myfile.is_open())
    {

        /* --------------Diffuse ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        getline(myfile, line);

        diffuseTexture = line.substr(line.find("diffuse:") + 8, line.length() - 8);

        if (!std::experimental::filesystem::exists(diffuseTexture)) //TODO check if is cross-plataform
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid diffuse texture path!"); //correct path checking
        }
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


        /* --------------Specular ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        getline(myfile, line);

        specularTexture = line.substr(line.find("specular:") + 9, line.length() - 9);

        if (!std::experimental::filesystem::exists(specularTexture))
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid specular texture map path!");
        }
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        /* --------------Displacement-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        getline(myfile, line);

        displacementTexture = line.substr(line.find("displacement:") + 13, line.length() - 13);

        if (!std::experimental::filesystem::exists(specularTexture))
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid displacement texture map path!");
        }
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        /* --------------Diffuse Slot -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        getline(myfile, line);
        try
        {
            diffSlot = std::stoi(line.substr(line.find("d_slot:") + 7, line.length() - 7));
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)//Check for invalid value in d slot!
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid diffuse slot value.");
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*


        /* --------------Specular Slot -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        getline(myfile, line);

        try
        {
            specSlot = std::stoi(line.substr(line.find("s_slot:") + 7, line.length() - 7));
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) //Check for invalid value in s slot!
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid specular slot value.");
        }

        /* --------------Displacement Slot ---------------------------------------------------------------*/

        getline(myfile, line);


        try
        {
            dispSlot = std::stoi(line.substr(line.find("ds_slot:") + 8, line.length() - 8));
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) //Check for invalid value in ds slot!
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid dispalcement slot value.");
        }


        /* --------------Shineness------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        getline(myfile, line);

        try
        {
            shineness = std::stof(line.substr(line.find("shineness:") + 10, line.length() - 10));
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) //Check for invalid shineness
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid shineness value.");
        }

        /* --------------Displacement Factor--------------------------------------------------------------*/
        getline(myfile, line);

        try
        {

            displacementFactor = std::stof(line.substr(line.find("displacement_factor:") + 20, line.length() - 20));
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) //Check for invalid value in slot!
        {
            MAGMA_FATAL("Invalid dispalcement factor value.");
        }
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


        /*▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬*/
        /*▬▬*/  this->_resName = filepath.substr(line.find("\res\materials") + 15, filepath.length() - 14);//Nome do Material!  //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  MAGMA_LOG("Material Name:" << _resName);                                                                        //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_diffuse = magma_new_resource<Texture>(diffuseTexture, TT_DIFFUSE);                                       //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_specular = magma_new_resource<Texture>(specularTexture, TT_TEXTURE_MAP);                                 //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_displacement = magma_new_resource<Texture>(displacementTexture, TT_TEXTURE_MAP);                         //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_diffuseSlot = diffSlot;                                                                                  //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_specularSlot = specSlot;                                                                                 //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_displacementSlot = dispSlot;                                                                             //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_shineness = shineness;                                                                                   //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬*/  this->_displacementFactor = displacementFactor;                                                                 //▬▬▬▬
        /*▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬*/

        myfile.close();

        return true;
    }
    /*==================================================================================================================*/

    return false;
}
```